# R statistics: Drawing multiple plots in RGL

Tags: r, 3d, rgl

Does anyone know how to draw multiple 3d plots in one picture using RGL in R Statistics.

I have three variables and each of those variables belong to two groups.  I want each group to have a different color so I can visualize it.  In regular R stats, I just use subset and then use par(new=T).  I haven't seen anything equivalent for the 3d plot.  Does anyone have any suggestion?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

try `plot3d(x, y, z, add=TRUE)`

Admittedly I was a bit surprised when it worked, I thought it would throw an error on the first plot, but i guess it creates an existing plot if none exists and otherwise adds the points to the existing plot